# UWP Page "Dispose" Event

Tags: xaml, memory-leaks, uwp

Is there a way to tell when the `Page` is `"Disposed"`?

I'm aware of the `Loaded / Unloaded` events, but unfortunately for my use case, `Unloaded` is triggered both on `Frame` forward and backwards navigation.

I'm interested in knowing when the `Page` was removed from the `Frame`'s "backstack", or the entire `Frame` was dismissed altogether.

Just to give you a little bit more context, my `Page` has a `ViewModel` which registers itself in the constructor on an event of a singleton object.

I could move the registration / unregistration in `Loaded / Unloaded` but I'd like my `ViewModel` to be notified even when its `Page` isn't visible on the screen but it is in the "backstack" of the `Frame`.

I agree that it looks like a bit of a design / code smell, but I still think a `"Dispose"` method would make sense on the Page, for the case were you can't ever reach it again.

Thanks,
Cosmin

Comment: Since the `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Page` class does not implement `IDisposable`, I do not understand what you mean by "disposed". Also, there's a big difference between some object being "disposed", and the user navigating backwards (which may not involved disposing or discarding any data whatsoever). Please fix your question so that it is clear what you are asking.

Comment: Hi, I've tried to clarify the question. I'm interested in some sort of callback that tells me when the Page is removed from the Frame's "backstack" or the Frame it self is closed (and you can't ever navigate to the same instance of that Page again)

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to be notified only when the backwards navigation takes place.

For yout requirement, here is an advice:

Use `NavigationMode` to determine how to navigate to the current page:

```cs
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.Back)
    {
        // Code here
    }
}
```

Adding this method to the target page can help you determine if the page is back navigation.

According to your other statement, you want to be notified when the page is **"Disposed"**. This is not necessary in UWP. You only need to check the page status when the software navigates to the page.

---

**Update**

Each navigation creates a new instance of the specific Page (or subclass) requested, and disposes the previous page instance. This happens even when navigating back to a previously visited page or when the new page type is the same as the previous page type. Apps that involve frequent navigation to the same pages can cache and reuse the page instances to make navigation more efficient.

To do this, set:

```cs
public YourPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Enabled;
}
```

Best regards.

Comment: Hi, I've tried to clarify the question. I'm interested in some sort of callback that tells me when the Page is removed from the Frame's "backstack" or the Frame it self is closed (and you can't ever navigate to the same instance of that Page again)

Comment: Page doesn't have "Dispose" or related events, but if you create an instance of a page and want to reuse it, you can learn about caching, see my modified answer :)